# Annotation callout not working Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, mapkit, mkannotationview

I'm trying to add a callout to my annotations in MapKit, but I cannot get it working after searching quite a bit online.

This is how I am currently creating each annotation which works fine at the moment.

```
struct loc {
    let title: String
    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double
    let phone: Int
    //let subTitle: String
}

var locs = [
    loc(title: "New York, NY",    latitude: 40.713054, longitude: -74.007228, phone: 2334), //subTitle: "Sub title"),
    ]

func placeAnnotations() {
    let annotations = locs.map { location -> MKAnnotation in
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.title = location.title
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)

        //annotation.subtitle = location.subTitle
        return annotation
    }
    mapView.addAnnotations(annotations)
}
```

(I have a function which adds data to the array locs)

And this is what I have got when trying to add a callout which isn't working.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation { return nil }
    let identifier = "pin"
    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) as? MKPinAnnotationView
    if annotationView == nil {
        annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
        annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .infoDark)
    } else {
        annotationView?.annotation = annotation
    }

    return annotationView
}
```

Comment: did you set `mapView.delegate` to `UIViewController` with `mapView..` function?

Comment: No I don't think I have, I just attempted to do that but it ended up crashing. How would I go about doing this properly?

Comment: you should `mapView.delegate = self`, why does it crash?

Comment: That's what i did but I needed to cast it with `as! MKMapViewDelegate`. And I have no idea why it crashes I can provide more information if needed.

Comment: you should add `class MyViewController: MKMapViewDelegate .. {}`

Comment: That works but the callout still isnt working

Comment: is it called? add `print` before `if annotation is MKUserLocation { return nil }`

Comment: No it isnt called

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153247/discussion-between-maxkrissigo-and-juicyfruit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView!
```

That will certainly never be called. In Swift 3, the correct signature is:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?
```